# can i call more than one function in isolated scope?

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive

Hi i am trying to invoke a function on a parent scope from within an isolated scope. i have 2 functions but only one function is working but the second one is always not working,

```
.directive('dirctiveName', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'AE',
            replace:true,
            scope: {
                parent_function1: '&',
                parent_function2: '&',
                alert: '=',
                isorder: '='
            },
            templateUrl: "app/pages/dashboard/card.html",
            controller: function ($scope, $interval) {

                $scope.function2= function () {
                    $scope.parent_function2();
                };

                $scope.function1 = function () {
                    $scope.parent_function1();
                };
          }
```

i have a dashboard.html with dashboardCtrl controller and it contains

```
  $scope.parent_function1= function () {
         //  will do some code
        };

  $scope.parent_function2= function () {
            //  will do some code
        };
```

here is the card.html code

```
<div class="card-header" style="background-color:{{color}}"> 
   <button ng-click="function1()" class=" btn btn-success">
     call function1
   </button> 
   <button ng-click="function2()" class=" btn btn-success"> 
     call function2 
   </button>
</div>
```

does directive only run one function??

thank you

Comment: Please add or link to a minimal, working example.

Comment: where are you calling these functions ? from `card.html` ? post your `card.html` as well. Also, any console errors ?

Comment: <div class="card-header" style="background-color:{{color}}">
    <button ng-click="function1()" class=" btn btn-success"> call function1</button>
    <button ng-click="function2()" class=" btn btn-success"> call function2  </button>
</div>

Comment: Please read [MCVE]

Comment: i have updated the post

Comment: Avoid using underscores `_` in attribute names. Use [camelCase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case) in controllers and [kebab-case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letter_case#Special_case_styles) in templates. For more information, see [AngularJS Developer Guide - Directives - Normalization](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#normalization).

Comment: Can you please provide the code that invoke the directive `<dirctive-name ...>` ?

Answer (score 0):

i found the issue, i forgot to add the attribute to the directive